# What are the steps to convert a Ruby on Rails app into an Phonegap iOS app?

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a site built on top of Rails. In essence, I want to release a lightweight version of it for the appstore, and I think Phonegap is a good solution w/o writing a full iOS application.

What would be the easiest way to get something like this out of the door?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at these:

1. [PhoneGap and rails 3: How to interact with a rails 3 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219333/phonegap-and-rails-3-how-to-interact-with-a-rails-3-app)
2. [Rails 3 / PhoneGap: Converting a Rails app into an Phonegap iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218686/rails-3-phonegap-converting-a-rails-app-into-an-phonegap-ios-app)
3. [Using Phonegap as a native container for a Rails 3 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713997/using-phonegap-as-a-native-container-for-a-rails-3-app)
4. [Rails 3.2 and phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504333/rails-3-2-and-phonegap)

This Kanna framework looks interesting too, allowing you to use a gem to unite Rails and Cordova/Phonegap:

https://github.com/SonicGarden/kanna