# How to use Phonegap with Ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am making a mobile web app with ruby on rails 3.
how can i use phonegap at its best ? Any suggestions? The web app will be appearing native to the client. App consist of google maps api v3. Its the same MVC except V->html/erb with google map.

Answer (score 3):

There are some posts you can take a look at:

- [PhoneGap and rails 3: How to interact with a rails 3 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219333/phonegap-and-rails-3-how-to-interact-with-a-rails-3-app)
- [Rails 3 / PhoneGap: Converting a Rails app into an Phonegap iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218686/rails-3-phonegap-converting-a-rails-app-into-an-phonegap-ios-app)
- [Using Phonegap as a native container for a Rails 3 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713997/using-phonegap-as-a-native-container-for-a-rails-3-app)