# developing mobile application for my rails app

Tags: android, iphone, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a rails 3 application which is simple social network and it currently running , I need to make a mobile application for android and Iphone ,I searched many times and I found jquery mobile and phonegap,sencha touch and many resources but what I need is a mobile application like a native app 
what is the best way to make a mobile application that connects with my existing rails server,I don't want to learn java or objective-c
Edit :my priority now is to make an android application for my social network

Comment: Phonegap will compile your html/css/js apps to the native mobile platform.

Comment: rails use html.erb extension and for js.erb too ,does it support compiling it too ?

Comment: Those files are what Rails uses to compile html/css/js. Once you have the rendered html you can use it with Phonegap

Comment: do you have any good resources for using rails with phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

Search around on this site first; this question is not new:

[How to use Phonegap with Ruby on rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809642/how-to-use-phonegap-with-ruby-on-rails-3)

There are some posts you can take a look at:

[PhoneGap and rails 3: How to interact with a rails 3 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219333/phonegap-and-rails-3-how-to-interact-with-a-rails-3-app)

[Rails 3 / PhoneGap: Converting a Rails app into an Phonegap iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218686/rails-3-phonegap-converting-a-rails-app-into-an-phonegap-ios-app)

[Using Phonegap as a native container for a Rails 3 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713997/using-phonegap-as-a-native-container-for-a-rails-3-app)

Answer (score 0):

You could easily make an android app with a web view. The web view would show the user your website inside the app. You can easily make it using web view

Follow this tutorial [https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/gettingstarted]

Comment: I need an application not a web page inside an application ,its like loading an iframe inside a web page ,I will begin with jquery mobile and phonegap