# Using Phonegap as a native container for a Rails 3 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, cordova

I'm looking into using PhoneGap for an iOS app so that I can utilize the camera API. The plan is to use Rails to manage the entire experience. At this point, I'm not particularly concerned about performance. If it wasn't for the need for the camera, I would simply design it as a true web app.

Most of the answers and tutorials I have found suggest using ajax to the backend server to render the frontend. At this point in the app development, I'm not sure I want to build so much of the view in JS and would prefer to use Rails to render the views. I have seen a few very brief references to use PhoneGap as a container to literally render the Rails app. Performance aside, is this possible and how would I set up the core html file in PhoneGap to let the mobile app run normally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not believe such a container exists to run on the client side but it is possible to dynamically serve a PhoneGap app (i.e. the app acts as a web browser with native functionality available via javascript commands).

[Here](https://github.com/RudyIndustries/Web-Frameworks-for-Mobile-App-Development) is code which demonstrate exactly what you are describing.

[Here](http://vimeo.com/35998909) is a screen cast I did associated with demo.

NOTE: The demo is using an out 3.2.1, and is broken as of the latest version Xcode and/or PhoneGap but it is possible, and apps of this nature are valid in the the various app stores, ([Linkedin](http://venturebeat.com/2012/05/02/linkedin-ipad-app-engineering/#s:1-linkedin-ipad) alongwith many others are already doing it.)  The logic is there I just haven't had the time to fix the bug with the new version of Xcode, or update the PhoneGap code (doing the update may actually fix the bug in one quick work session).

Comment: Thanks rudolph, I can't upvote you due to my reputation score, but I think this will point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Rudolph, can Facebook Connect work in this dynamically served approach?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can also check my example app that is exported to *Phoengap*. It doesn't use camera but it is possible to combine native parts with Phonegap.

https://github.com/joscas/base_app/tree/devel (currently in the devel branch for the exportable version)

Life deploy: https://starter-app-staging.herokuapp.com (the desktop version)

It is based on *rails* / *ember.js* plus with token authentication (ember-auth) + OAuth (Google, LinkedIn,..) and *Devise*.

It uses the ([phonegap-rails](https://github.com/joscas/phonegap-rails)) gem I've created to export assets, fix paths etc.

Comment: Is this still the best way to get a rails web app working on Android/iOS as native app ?