# Rails 3.2 and phonegap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova

I have a rails application currently running ,I want to make a mobile application for it ,I don't want to learn objective-c or java ,I read many articles about phonegap and how I can use it to make a cross platform web apps
Phonegap compile css/htm/js 
Rails application has its ruby code and also html.erb and js.erb extensions
So how can I make a mobile application ,mainly for android for ex as a back-end of my rails excising server
I will use jquery mobile as a UI for the application 
Do I need to make an api and use emberjs or angularjs or backbone to contact with the server ?
Tutorials in using rails as a back-end for a mobile application are so rare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, there is no a single way to do this. So, I'll tell you the tools I use when have to build a **mobile client working with API server** app.

Backend:

1. [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)
2. [rabl gem](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) (Ruby API Builder Language) is a Rails and Padrino ruby templating system for generating JSON, XML, MessagePack, PList and BSON. With this gem you can:

   - Create arbitrary nodes named based on combining data in an object
   - Pass arguments to methods and store the result as a child node
   - Render partial templates and inherit to reduce code duplication
   - Rename or alias attributes to change the name from the model
   - Append attributes from a child into a parent node
   - Include nodes only if a certain condition has been met

Frontend:

1. [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/): set of device APIs that allow a mobile app developer to access native device function such as the camera or accelerometer from JavaScript.
2. [Angularjs](http://angularjs.org/) (Optional)
3. [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) (If you choose to work with Angular): Free and open source, library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components. Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS. Ionic comes with an [AngularJS and Cordova Seed Project example](http://ionicframework.com/tutorials/) you can use to start your won app.
4. [angular-restmod](https://github.com/platanus/angular-restmod) (If you choose to work with Angular): Rails inspired REST-API ORM. With this you can have "javascript models" to interact with your Rails API. If you don't want to use this you can use [Angular's $http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

With Ember you can use [ember_phonegap_starter](https://github.com/ianpetzer/ember_phonegap_starter). This is a starter kit to get you up and running with Ember inside a mobile application. This can be dumped inside a PhoneGap wrapper to create an App wrapper for your Ember application. (check out the [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bs6xz-pxBVU))

You can use [bootstrap-for-ember](https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember) ([examples](http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/dist/)) to add Twitter Bootstrap 3 to your Ember app.

Comment: do you have any options for ember ,so I can accept that answer

Comment: in spite I know all of these resources but you made me choosing what I will do ,you organised your answer very well ,so I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the solution but an attempt on how I would do it if I were to use these technologies. The way I can see you pull this off is to use RubyonRails as Backend Sever that fetches REST API. [Look here](http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/sample-rest-api-example-in-rails/) and [there](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning) to see how it can be achieved. So in essence RuybOnRails server will perform fetching REST API services.

Then, in PhoneGap you could use Backbone.js, [Look here](http://backbonetutorials.com/) for more info, to perform your GET/POST/CRUD requests. Hope this helps.

Comment: do you have any tutorials for using both three techs. together I mean Rails Api ,Backbone or emberjs with Phonegap

Comment: Please look [here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/02/sample-mobile-app-with-backbone-js-and-phonegap/): THEN [Part One:](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/), [Part Two:](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-2-crud/) and [Part Three:](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-3-deep-linking-and-application-states/) for Backbone and PhoneGap examples. Hope it helps

Comment: I prefere emberjs more than backbone ,but any way thanks for your answers

Comment: actually ,It's not the answer for what I need ,I know backbonejs very well ,and I am fan of emberjs ,my Api is really so huge and I am using many techs ,nodejs ,nosql dbs ,Bson ..

Comment: If you have used Node.js why do you want to use Rails REST-API? Wouldn't it be easier to use that  you know (Node.js) ? pluse MongoDB would be a fit match for you supporting data with Node.js.

Comment: I use Nodejs in adding a bit real time features for my app ,but Rails is the back end also my app is currently working since 2 years

Comment: Oh ok. Regardless. If you are unaware, I have given you some link to look at on creating Rails API.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a API.  I had a similar situation, and used just Rails, Cordova/PhoneGap, Bootstrap, and a few Cordova plugins.

I ran into 2 main gothchas: how to get the correct assets loaded into the app's page, and how to tell an app access from a "browser" access on the same device.

My app required that I have a slightly different set of plugins for iOS and Android.  So I needed a way to bundle up just the right set for each.  I used multiple manifest files in the app/assets/javascripts directory to handle that.

I also modified the user-agent strings coming from my Cordova apps.  By default, you can't really tell a "browser" GET from a Cordova app GET.